# How to implement List/Array pagination with a pivot (different starting points) and that is circular in Python?

Tags: python, pagination

I'm not sure how to start this question and also what does it mean that it is circular?

Answer (score 0):

Circular means that when the pagination reaches the end of the list it loops back to the start again.

To give an example, `dblist` contains a list of IDs and you need to write a function called `getPage` which returns a certain page. The function takes arguments `pivotID` which is the first ID of the first page, `pageSize` which is the number of IDs in each page, and the `pageNum` which is the page you want to return. When the end of the list is reached it should loop back to the beginning of the list and continue until reaching the `pivotID` before stopping. I found the easiest way to do this was to rewrite `dblist` with the `pivotID` as the first element in the list.

```
dblist = [13, 5, 6, 54, 82, 39, 11, 69, 96, 32, 48, 18, 45, 77, 99]

def getPage(dbList, pivotID, pageSize, pageNum):
    startIndex = dbList.index(pivotID)
    dbList = dbList[startIndex:] + dbList[:startIndex]

    startPos = pageNum * pageSize
    endPos = startPos + pageSize

    if endPos < len(dbList):
        return dbList[startPos:endPos]
    elif startPos < len(dbList):
        return dbList[startPos:]
    else:
        return []
```

Choose some parameters for this function and print out the first 10 pages

```
print("PageNum Page")
for i in range(10):
    print("{}\t{}".format(i, getPage(dblist, 69, 2, i)))

PageNum Page
0   [69, 96]
1   [32, 48]
2   [18, 45]
3   [77, 99]
4   [13, 5]
5   [6, 54]
6   [82, 39]
7   [11]
8   []
9   []
```